# How to hide overflowing content in CSS?

Tags: css

I have a long text and I want to hide that part if it is longer than the div.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the div with a width or height, (otherwise it won't know whether something is overflowing). Then, add the `overflow:hidden;` CSS property-value pair.

If using IE, remember to position the element relative so that IE knows how to deal with it.

I wouldn't use ellipsis, as its not fully cross-browser compatible

Demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/vxN8v/1/

Comment: As of the time of this answer, all major browsers have supported the `ellipsis` value for the `text-overflow` property. Per [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp), it goes back as far as Chrome 4, IE6, Firefox 7, Safari 3.1, and Opera 11.

Comment: Although in Graeme's defense, some of these had only been released a few months after his post.

Comment: but , when i use this for p tag inside a slider, it is not obeying..for example assume i need o diaplay a product name which is lengthy,i need to display that name with (...)at first line end , what to do

Answer (score 3):

use `text-overflow: ellipsis;`. Note that the containing element needs an explicit width in order for ellipsis to take effect, and you won't get an ellipsis in Firefox.

Comment: overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Assign some width to div so that if your text flow out of that box will get hidden.